# SELinux + logrotate + prerotate = Permission Denied

Tags: selinux, logrotate

I have what (should) be a fairly straightforward task:
Migrate a set of custom log files to a database at night.

I use logrotate (cron.daily) with a simple prerotate task

```
/var/log/myapplog/*.log
{
    daily
    copytruncate
    rotate 366
    dateext
    dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
    compress
    missingok
    compresscmd /usr/bin/xz
    compressoptions -ze9
    compressext .xz
    prerotate
        /usr/local/myapp/bin/DBWriter $1
    endscript
}
```

Unfortunately SELinux doesn't see it that way.  If I `setenforce 0` then the script runs perfectly.  Rotates logs, sends them to the DB, etc.
`setenforce 1`, however, returns :

`logrotate_script: line 1: /usr/local/myapp/bin/DBWriter: Permission denied`

I've tried changing contexts on DBWriter, most recently I set it to `unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t` which did not work either...

Ideally, I need to keep SELinux enabled.  If it matters, DBWriter is also available as a java .jar file.  But running `java -jar DBWriter.jar` has the same result.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: Win.T's answer below solved the problem for me.

```
semanage permissive -a logrotate_t
```

Part of the problem is that I was trying to do *exactly* what SELinux is designed to prevent: cause process A to execute unknown file B and wreak havoc on system C

Project design considerations and restrictions put us on this path.

Clients don't always want to hear about those fancy buzz words like security and future-proofing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an SELinux helper daemon that you can run that dumps a logfile with the exact command you need to do to allow the things that just failed. The name escapes me at the moment, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/audit/audit.log` (if you have `auditd` running). You can also use `audit2allow` to view SELinux error messages and possible solutions.

Additionally, try `semanage permissive -a logrotate_t` to allow logrotate to run and not be denied by SELinux.

Comment: audit.log doesn't help much.  It just says it failed.
messages doesn't give me much to go on either.

Comment: @SeanEichhorn try adding this semanage fcontext : #semanage permissive -a logrotate_t. This should allow logrotate to run and not denied by Selinux even it is set as enforcing. Remember to perform a restorecon -R -v

Comment: See [access.redhat.com/solutions/39006](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/39006) for a complete explanation of the problem and the solution.

Comment: Is the ````semanage permissive -a logrotate_t```` persistent? Does it persist reboots?

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure it's SELinux, first try temporarily disabling SELinux enforcing `sudo setenforce 0` [SELinux Ref](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/) and run the code that was failing. If it is SELinux read on..

I ran into this issue recently and was pretty unfamiliar with SELinux so it was a bit of a learning curve for me. Unlike (DAC) standard posix mode permissions using `chmod` & `chown`, SELinux is a lot more granular with it's permissions. It will in certain cases deny specific operations such as connecting to the internet over TCP/443, or allow writing to /foo & /bar, but nowhere else etc. depending on the caller (application).

To view a files (MAC) mandatory access control permissions `ls -Z` or users `id -Z` with output in the `user:role:type:level` format.

In my case on Centos7 I had a script called in a logrotate.d conf file with a prerotate script that would upload a logfile before it was rotated. I was having several denials (logged to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`). I learned you can use a few tools to generate specific policy package to install. I am creating .rpm packages for our code, so I added all the steps below to the .spec file to generate & install a policy package during time of install.

**What you'll need:** policycoreutils-python, checkpolicy (might already be installed)

From what I understand if you plan on distributing this security policy the idea is you want to only ship the *.te file and generate the policy onsite so if the definitions that policy relies on get updated, they will be inherited at time of install.

**#finding the denial messages**

```
watch "tail /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep 'denied'"
```

**# creating the te (type enforcement) file (human readable security policy)**

```
grep 1561055176.928:11371 /var/log/audit/audit.log|audit2allow -m myapp > myapp.te
```

**# you can also grep a few failures and pipe them all to audit2allow**

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep logrotate | audit2allow -m myapp > myapp.te
```

**# you can also use audit2why to give you a little explanation of why it failed sometimes with remediation steps**

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep logrotate | audit2why
```

**WARNING** During this step I found audit2why reporting my script would work if I ran `setsebool -P nis_enabled 1`. While that sounds fine and dandy you should **always** lookup what the security implications are of running those commands. Setting this may broaden your attack surface, so user beware.

**# build a policy module from type enforcement file**

```
checkmodule -M -m -o myapp.mod myapp.te
```

**# build a policy package from policy module**

```
semodule_package -o myapp.pp -m myapp.mod
```

**# load policy package with root privs**

```
semodule -i myapp.pp
```

I had to do these steps several times until I had accumulated all the tiny permissions my code needed to operate.

-- update --

I ended up running my script inline just before the logrotate cron task so that I didn't have to expand logrotate_t's permissions. I had it in prerotate because I wanted not to rotate the file on failures, which this syntax still satisfies. Using the '&&' syntax if the 1st command fails it won't execute the 2nd.

```
10 * * * * root /usr/bin/sudo -i -u otheruser /opt/send_logs.sh && /usr/sbin/logrotate -f /path/to/myapp_logrotate.conf > /tmp/myapp_rotate.log 2&1
```